# unix:how to sort the bcp file based on the columns using sort utility?

Tags: unix

Hi i have a requirement to sort the bcp file based on the column filed value.here field separator is used as \x01 and row separa
tor is used as \x02.All the information is stored in the single line of bcp file.
I have tried with the below query

sort -t  \x01 -z\x02 -k2n,2n  -o sorted_data_`date "+%m%d%y%H%M%S"`.bcp /BNYM/act_agent_events_AgDrCUa5Uiw7kHq5NgGoIBWs_133456.bcp

But it does not sorted based on the second column
m
Attaching the bcp file.
please help me on how do we sort the file based on second column(after the date value)

### Data in bcp file

2012-04-16 10:35:16.117BAAAAC0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAABY25JFX6XZfri6NgGoIBWs30004373120010840/LogisticsMgr/DeliveryLogisticsMgrDeliveryCheckStatusLogisticsMgrqwQzeSlY7aWIcu6jFxHS/Q==wBkxsG+SGmPkV8Cz7LoMvw==logistics652841288162400nbhydsoletixp9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.120BAAAAB0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAADUsVwslC8nf7i6NgGoIBWs30003762320010090/AccountMgmt/BillingAccountMgmtBillingChargeAccountAccountMgmtdNCvO/2f5LX3BjewCbfCaA==zhdycSzBtfdvoeEC8hPLfA==finance652845508162400nbhydsoletixp9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.137AQBRv3dT4YnZfri6NgGoIBWs0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAABRv3dT4YnZfri6NgGoIBWs30003044870011040/OrderManagement/OrderingOrderManagementOrderingCheckStatusOrderManagementPTWWE0wTSwsQZMYEQ4g6RQ==0KtezUvQkOOkSrTAhl455w==ordermgmt652841378162400ordermgmt1.writenow.com9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.109AAAoQXS2OW7Zfri6NgGoIBWs0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAAAoQXS2OW7Zfri6NgGoIBWs30003913990010760/StockApp/StockServiceStockAppStockServiceStockCheckStockAppV3UuJQeiUa4b+DydaHy3FQ==mnn8+QVDZ+Clj8Fyz7ddsA==warehouseamericas652841368162400nbhydsoletixp9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.102AcD0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAACs2k00egPZfri6NgGoIBWs30003443250010840/LogisticsMgr/DeliveryLogisticsMgrDeliveryCheckStatusLogisticsMgrqwQzeSlY7aWIcu6jFxHS/Q==wBkxsG+SGmPkV8Cz7LoMvw==logistics652841288162400nbhydsoletixp9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.141QAqSPLPSqLZfri6NgGoIBWs0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAAAqSPLPSqLZfri6NgGoIBWs30003973920011080/OrderingServices/OrderingOrderingServicesOrderingCheckStatusOrderingServicesCVim6lKsl/QGDrErqenNdg==13RQpOOyOFvxX7p5dAzVdQ==customergw652841248172400custgw1.writenow.com9.00002012-04-16 10:35:16.125AQDO.WX2ikQnf7i6NgGoIBWs0000-6TgTbL12lFR9uTYB-8A0251CAAADO.WX2ikQnf7i6NgGoIBWs30003943690010140/AccountMgmt/BillingAccountMgmtBillingChargeAccountAccountMgmtdNCvO/2f5LX3BjewCbfCaA==zhdycSzBtfdvoeEC8hPLfA==finance652845508162400nbhydsoletixp9.0000

Comment: can't you sort it as part of the export select query, or once it is in the database? It might also help if you rephrase you question in simpler terms, i.e. rather that that big `1 line of data(?)` , make 2-3 small lines of data that have the field and row seperators you need with simple data for 2-3 columns, not the whole record. Of it works for the small sample, it should work for your larger data, right? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your raw file to play with, but I think this might work.

sort -t \x01 -z \x02 -k 2n

Faced with this problem, I'd use sed to massage it then pipe it to sort.

Also, if you have any control over how the bcp command gets run, you can add the -c option to give it a newline, which should simplify things.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx